# adding xapian library in cmake

Tags: cmake, xapian

I am trying to add xapian search engine library in cmake file

```
project(search)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(Xapian REQUIRED)

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${Xapian_LIBRARY}
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

This is not working can any one tell me how to add this if i compile with -lxapian it works

Comment: What does not work? Any error messages?

Comment: It gives the xapian library is not linked.

Comment: main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `Xapian::WritableDatabase::WritableDatabase(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap `target_link_libraries()` and `add_executable()` calls. You can link library only to already defined target.

And use `${XAPIAN_LIBRARIES}` instead of `${Xapian_LIBRARY}`.

Comment: can u explain the difference between ${XAPIAN_LIBRARIES} and ${Xapian_LIBRARY}

Comment: Sure, there is no `${Xapian_LIBRARY}`. Here are variables that Xapian-Config.cmake defines: https://github.com/xapian/xapian/blob/master/xapian-core/cmake/xapian-config.cmake.in